# How to delete a query using mysqli with join tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What am I doing wrong?
Why am I unable to delete the results? 
My syntax below
The Select statement works like a charm but for some reason when I want to delete the specific ID it does not do anything. Only says error..
Any idea what am I doing wrong and if you can please point me in the right direction? thank you

```
require_once 'includes/mysqli_connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) { 

$sql = "SELECT n.entry, FROM `customers` AS c INNER JOIN `notes` as n ON c.user_id = n.user_id WHERE c.user_id={$_GET['id']}";

$result_db = $dbc->query($sql) or die ("Error!");

if ($result_db->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result_db->fetch_assoc()) {

echo    '<form action="select_delete.php" method="post">

' . $row['registration_date'] . '<br/>' . $row['entry'] .'
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '"/>
<input id="click" type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete this Entry" /></form>';
}
} else{
echo 'Information was not retrieved';
}
```

QUERY TO DELETE

```
} elseif(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {

$results = $dbc->query("DELETE `customers`, `notes` FROM `customers` INNER JOIN `notes` ON `notes`.entry = `notes`.entry WHERE `customers`.user_id={$_POST['id']}";

if($results){
echo 'This entry has been deleted!';
} else {
'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
echo 'NOT DELETED';
}
} else {
echo 'Page accessed in error.. Login if administrator.';
}

$dbc->close();
```

Comment: use DELETE `customers`.*, `notes`.* FROM `customers` INNER JOIN `notes` ON `notes`.entry = `notes`.entry WHERE `customers`.user_id={$_POST['id']}

Comment: There is an issue somewhere.. it always jumps to NOT DELETED... can't figure out why.. it is like if it was not reading the query for some reason

Comment: What exactly error is printed along with it as you have printed error it might be giving error near   
WHERE condition as you have used {} instead of quotes. I have never used curly braces this might be error

Comment: it does not tell me.. it ignores the query and it just jumps to where I echo NOT DELETED... it does not show any error.. i it just doesn't say..  I use the curly braces because the information comes from another submitted form by customers POST method.. I can always grab it that way

Comment: try printing $result  it might help you

Comment: Just seen one another issue you have just gathered error but have not printed error

Comment: `ON \`notes\`.entry = \`notes\`.entry`? Should one of those `\`notes\`` be `\`customers\``?

Comment: yeah.. error reporting  is acting up.. smh..

Comment: @Sean yeah I guess.. I am tired of trying different ways..

Comment: Am I supposed to execute somewhere? I have tested the code elsewhere and I works fine.. I don't know if it is because it is not grabbing the ID

Answer (score 1):

while using JOIN in delete statement we need to specify what to delete so

Use 
customers.*, notes.*

Final Query:

```
"DELETE `customers`, `notes` FROM `customers` INNER JOIN `notes` ON `notes`.entry = `notes`.entry WHERE `customers`.user_id='".$_POST['id']."'"
```